# What is best to use in Ajax calls in asp.net - Webservices or Generic handlers?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

What is the pros and cons of webservices (.asmx) vs handlers (.ashx) for ajax calls. 
Is there any? I think handlers are kind of better because you don't get so much bloat as you would with webservices. Any advice or suggestions of either practice?

Comment: This doesn't fit your or, put for building web services I've started to leverage building them in MVC controller actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using handlers primarily for the reason you suggest.  There's additional overhead with web web services, which were designed for heavier SOAP operations, as opposed to an HttpHandler.

Additionally, a lot of that SOAP information isn't often needed for AJAX calls.  Let's say that I just want to return some JSON to the page.  Building a .NET web service which does this, in my opinion, breaks the concept of what a .NET web service is.  A handler can indeed be anything, but a web service generally implies a SOAP or WCF contract of some kind.  Not just outputting some JSON and ending the response.  (Maybe I've missed a JSON web service feature somewhere, that's entirely possible.  This is just the approach I've taken.)  So, again at least for me, it's also a matter of separation of concerns in the design.